Autocomplete for global CSS variables stops working if I use Tailwind VS Code Extension
The VS code extension for Tailwind requires you to set file associations in VS code settings to tailwind.
"files.associations": {
  "*.css": "tailwindcss"
}

With this, we can use the theme function like this theme(colors.gray.100) in CSS files. However, this seems to break the built-in intellisense autocomplete for CSS variables. So, if I have the following file, variables like --color1 don't autocomplete in other CSS files.
/* globals.css */
:root {
  --color1: red;
  --color2: blue;
}

This can be fixed by changing the file associations to css. However, that breaks the tailwind extension and any CSS file that uses the theme() function starts showing lint errors.
"files.associations": {
  "*.css": "css"
}

How do I get both Tailwind and CSS variables autocomplete to work simultaneously? The file associations seems to take a string and doesn't accept an array.
